# Update min max date with join

Tags: sql, sql-update

I have 2 tables CONT and CUMU, the two table have the same field named RAPP(txt property)

In CONT have a filed named DATA (as date short)

In CUMU have a field DAL (FROM in english) and a field AL (TO in english)

With a join on RAPP, i need to extract the Min and Max Date from CONT.DATA and insert Min date value in DAL and Max date value in AL

How to with a query?

note;
i work with ADO, Access databse and vb6 classic

Answer (score 0):

You could write a query to update all records like this:

```
UPDATE
  CUMU, CONT
SET 
  CUMU.DAL = (SELECT DISTINCT MIN(CONT.DATA) FROM CONT WHERE CONT.RAPP = CUMU.RAPP),
  CUMU.AL = (SELECT DISTINCT MAX(CONT.DATA) FROM CONT  WHERE CONT.RAPP = CUMU.RAPP)
WHERE 
  CONT.RAPP = CUMU.RAPP;
```

Try for yourself: [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/26d2d/1/0)

It's not particularly optimized, but for a relative small dataset it should suffice.

Comment: `CONT` in the UPDATE clause, and the WHERE clause [are unnecessary](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6c074/1). Anyway, the OP has stated that they are using MS Access. The MySQL syntax may not work.